# Subquery with multiple select statements

Tags: sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

to check the subquery having multiple select statement inside 'not in' condition

Eg.

```
select id from tbl where 
id not in (select id from table1) and 
id not in (select id from table2) and
id not in (select id from table3)
```

instead of repeating the same id 'not in' condition , i need the subquery which will check in one shot from multiple tables..

pls help..

Comment: your seemingly urgent question has been answered below.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a union, so you just have one `in`:

```
select  id
from    tbl 
where   id not in 
        (
        select id from table1
        union all select id from table2
        union all select id from table3
        )
```

Note: `not in` does not work well with nullable columns, but I assume `id` is not nullable here.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is better expressed as:

```
SELECT id 
FROM tbl t
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 on t1.id = t.id 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t2.id = t.id 
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 on t3.id = t.id 
WHERE t1.id IS NULL AND t2.id IS NULL AND t3.id IS NULL
```

Comment: (renumbered your tables, since you were left joining to table1 twice, and not at all to table3)

Answer (score 0):

use union all
like this -->
select f.FIRST_NAME from farmer f where f.ID in (select  v.ID  from Village v where v.ID in (1,2) union all select s.ID from state s where s.ID in (3,4) )